# How and when does Ghost load the CSS file?

Tags: css, ghost-blog

Perhaps the question is nonsense, but let me explain. I’m trying to modify my Ghost theme. When I make changes in the CSS file, nothing happens on the site. I’ve cleared the cash. I’ve even tried a new browser never before used to visit the site. Yet nothing, it’s as if the CSS formatting was never changed. Being a Ghost beginner, I’m wondering if perhaps I’m missing something fundamental here. Does Ghost point the browser toward the existing CSS file associated with the theme? Or are the CSS files loaded in some other manner, and “generated” for the browser to read?

Comment: Are you using the hosted version or are you self hosting? I haven't used Ghost but I assume it's using Webpack or similar to merge and compile your code which means you will need to use a build script of some kind before your changes are reflected in the actual code.

Comment: I’m self hosting. I wonder how to run such build script from the terminal. If anyone in here uses Ghost, I’d love to know more.

Comment: Looks like `ghost start` would probably do it. But I'm sure the cli has documentation.